# Issue with creating table from .sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to run a sql file on a mysql at this address
https://github.com/articDrag0n/PrepApp/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql

and I am getting an error
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 20: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ID)
)' at line 11

How do I fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not your version.  There is an error in the script. The create offerings should read (comma was missing after icon VARCHAR(255)):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS offerings;
CREATE TABLE offerings(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(255),
moderator TEXT,
moderator_email TEXT,
description TEXT,
location TEXT,
peopleLimit INT,
days TEXT,
icon VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```